# Android application's ic_launcher is not working

Tags: android

i have a application can't show ic_launcher. before asking question,i do like those:
 1. In my AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" ...>
...
</application>
```

1. there's a pic called ic_launcher in folder drawable.

but in launcher application's icon always can't show ic_launcher.
my android device can show xxhdpi source. so  i remove ic_launcher to folder xxhdpi, it can work fine. i want to know why.
please help,thank you .

Comment: did you tried cleaning your project ?

Comment: There could be many ic_launcher.png icon in different folders for different screen size, you have to replace all icon in all those folder.

Answer (score 0):

First Clean and build again your project. If you still facing same issue and if you are using Eclipse IDE then press "ctrl+space" after you typed android:icon="@drawable/ . All available image resource should come as a list. Then you choose appropriate icon for your application and re-run your application.

Comment: thank your answer.cleaning the project is not working. I put a ic_launcher picture to xxhdpi folder,then it works fine.